# laravel form binding : how to get id

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5

this is my form :

```
{{ Form::model($ggXml, ['route' => 'entegra.gg.index', $ggXml->id]) }}
...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

this is my post function :

```
public function ggPostIndex($id)
    {
        $ggXml = App\Http\Models\ggXml::findOrFail($id);
        $ggXml->fill($Imput::all());
        $ggXml->save();

        return Redirect::route('entegra.gg.index');*/
    }
```

how can i get ggXml->id in controller. in tutorial video he can but i can not

i got this error :

```
ErrorException in ggController.php line 24:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ggController::ggPostIndex()
```

this is my route :

```
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'entegra.gg.index',
        'uses' => 'ggController@ggGetIndex'
    ]);
    Route::post('/', [
        'as' => 'entegra.gg.index',
        'uses' => 'ggController@ggPostIndex'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `route` value with brackets

Try this

```
{{ Form::model($ggXml, ['route' => ['entegra.gg.index', $ggXml->id]]) }}
...
{{ Form::close() }}
```